# mssql failed to start centos

Tags: sql-server, centos7

I have ms sql installed in cenOS it works OK until just today. When I check its status It shows

> Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2018-03-05 15:30:33 +08; 546ms ago

So I run the command :

> systemctl start mssql-server

Below show the whole response from the terminal together with the solution and what it responded

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start mssql-server
Job for mssql-server.service failed because start of the service was attempted too often. See "systemctl status mssql-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
To force a start use "systemctl reset-failed mssql-server.service" followed by "systemctl start mssql-server.service" again.
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl reset-failed mssql-server.service
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start mssql-server.service
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status mssql-server.service
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2018-03-05 15:31:03 +08; 6s ago
     Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
  Process: 1664 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 1664 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

Mar 05 15:31:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mssql-server.service entered failed state.
Mar 05 15:31:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service failed.
Mar 05 15:31:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 05 15:31:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mssql-server.service
Mar 05 15:31:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
Mar 05 15:31:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mssql-server.service entered failed state.
Mar 05 15:31:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service failed.
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: Same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your linux is on a virtual machine, please ensure that the virtual machine's memory is greater than the sqlserver hardware requirement 3.5G